# How to call gotoAndStop within a movieclip that is within another movieclip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am using the World Construction Kit with flash to make a physics based game. I have a movieclip which serves as the world. I am creating a platformer and for now, when the player comes into contact with the goal it will send them to the main menu, each level is on a different frame in the movie clip and the menu is to.

this is the code when the goal is touched by the player

```
public function handleContact(e:ContactEvent):void {

        var g:goal = e.other.m_userData as goal;
        if (g) {
            trace(g.x + ", " + g.y);
            MovieClip(parent).gotoAndStop(2);
        }
```

the code is able to go to the next frame within the level movieclip, but how do I make it go up a level so that it can return to the main menu on the main timeline?

Edit: when I try parent.MovieClip(parent).gotoAndStop(2); MovieClip(parent).parent.gotoAndStop(2); give me the error 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method MovieClip through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer.

when I try MovieClip(parent).MovieClip(parent).gotoAndStop(2);, it compiles, but when I contact the goal I get this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1006: MovieClip is not a function.
    at fred/handleContact()[C:\Documents\sdrVG\fred.as:85]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at Box2DAS.Common::b2EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()[C:\API\wck-master\wck-master\Box2DAS\Common\b2EventDispatcher.as:27]
    at Box2DAS.Dynamics::b2ContactListener/ContactDispatch()[C:\API\wck-master\wck-master\Box2DAS\Dynamics\b2ContactListener.as:65]
    at Box2DAS.Dynamics::b2ContactListener/BeginContact()[C:\API\wck-master\wck-master\Box2DAS\Dynamics\b2ContactListener.as:31]
    at Box2DAS.Dynamics::b2World/BeginContact()[C:\API\wck-master\wck-master\Box2DAS\Dynamics\b2World.as:346]
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
    at global/AS3_CallTS()
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
    at Function/<anonymous>()
    at cmodule.Box2D::FSM__ZN13WorldListener12BeginContactEP9b2Contact/work()
```

Comment: have you tried `parent.parent.gotoAndStop(1);`

Comment: Dispatching an event to bubble up through the display list would be a better pattern.

Comment: @Adam I tried that and I get this error: 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method MovieClip through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer.

Comment: @Farjuan Looks like parent.parent is not a MovieClip, but just a DisplayObjectContainer. Look into what Jason said.

Comment: @Jason how would I go about doing that? I am sorry I am a noob so I have no idea how

Answer (score 0):

[Event capturing and bubbling](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a67edfb831266c0b5fc6-8000.html) can decouple awareness of objects on the display list.

You could introduce a game event class, implemented like:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class GameEvent extends Event
    {
        public static const NEXT_LEVEL:String = "NEXT_LEVEL";

        public function GameEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=true, cancelable:Boolean=false)
        {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        }
    }
}
```

From your player movie clip instance, you could dispatch this event which bubbles up through parents until captured.  For instance, from your `handleContact(e:ContactEvent)` function call:

```
dispatchEvent(new GameEvent(GameEvent.NEXT_LEVEL));
```

This event could be handled in your main class by adding a listener to handle the event.

Listen for `NEXT_LEVEL` events:

```
addEventListener(GameEvent.NEXT_LEVEL, nextLevelHandler);
```

On that next level game event, create a handler function:

```
protected function nextLevelHandler(event:GameEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Comment: thanks a bunch for going to the trouble and actually writing up all of that, I really appreciate it! but even though this works it still doesen't seem to be making the movie go to the frame on the main timeline, only in the movieclip it self, thank you so very much for your help!

Comment: Put the `nextLevelHandler` where needed, such as within actions on your main timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `MovieClip(this.parent)` to your function like so,

```
public function handleContact(e:ContactEvent):void
{
      var g:goal = e.other.m_userData as goal;

      if (g)
      {
            trace(g.x + ", " + g.y);
            MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndStop(2);
      }
}
```

Best luck.